# sympy output in IPython

Tags: python, ipython, sympy

I am very new to coding in Python and using the IPython notebook.

My question: is it possible to get the input-format of an output I get from previous calculations?  For example, if I obtain an output in latex like `$x^2$` how can I get `x**2` automatically?

Comment: What do you mean "to get the input format of an output I get from previous calculations"? Could you edit your own question to clarify it, possibly by adding some example code? --- NB to edit your question, click the "edit" button at the end of your Q.  --- PS if you'll fail to clarify your Q, it is going to be closed as "unclear what you're asking:...

Comment: thanks for suggestions. I fixed grammatical errors. I am trying to add some lines of code to make clear what I'm asking for

Comment: There isn't always a convenient 'input form' that will recreate the object being output. For many simple objects - like numbers, strings, lists and dicts - the repr that is output can be evaluated, but this isn't always true. In IPython, however, if you see the `Out [8]` prompt, you can use `Out[8]` in your code to get that object for later calcuations.

Comment: Why would you want to get the string representation when you can get nice Latex output using simpy in ipython notebook? use `init_printing(use_latex='mathjax')` at the top of your script and any subsequent sympy equations will be formarted with Mathjax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call `str` on the expression. For example

```
>>> from sympy import symbols
>>> x = symbols('x')
>>> str(x**2)
'x**2'
```